# Subquery from the same table

Tags: mysql, subquery

TABLE STRUCTURE

```
[place]
p.place_id
p.name
p.image
p.address
p.phone
p.website
p.description
p.lng
p.lat
p.distance
p.last_update
p.is_ad

SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM place p
```

I need to select all records, which contains 2 RANDOM records with flag "is_ad" = 1

so for ex:

Record:

```
1 is_ad 0
2 is_ad 1
3 is_ad 0
4 is_ad 1
5 is_ad 0
6 is_ad 1
7 is_ad 0
```

show random two records first position

```
1 is_ad 1 
6 is_ad 1
3 is_ad 0
4 is_ad 0
5 is_ad 0
7 is_ad 0
7 is_ad 0
```

it should show at first position

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to update the expected result a bit: 7 is_ad 0 is present twice; 1 is_ad 0 is changed to 1 is_ad 0, 2 is_ad 1 is missing and 4 is_ad 1 has also changed to 4 is_ad 0.

Comment: You can do by using sql function rand() for example,
`SELECT * FROM table
WHERE is_ad = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM place where is_ad = 1 order by rand() limit 2)
union all
(SELECT * FROM place where is_ad <> 1 order by place_id)
```